# "In my own words"

Tags: modismos, pronombres, infinitivo

In English when I'm learning something new and complex from a patient teacher, I often like to try to repeat a part of what the teacher told me in my own words.

In English, I might say something like this:

> I will try to repeat what you said in my own words: The only way to destroy the One Ring is to drop it into the Crack of Doom.

or

> If I understand correctly, the only way to destroy the One Ring is to drop it into the Crack of Doom.

Are there common ways in Spanish to explain that I am about to repeat something back to my teacher in my own words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual expressions for this are similar to the English ones:

- Lo repito con mis propias palabras: la única manera de destruir el Anillo es tirarlo a la Grieta del Destino [...]
- Si lo he entendido bien, [...]
- A ver si lo he entendido: [...]

Answer (score 3):

"In my own words" / Con mis propias palabras

Según los contextos las frases utilizadas serán unas u otras, en todo caso son muy parecidas al inglés.

- Si he oído bien... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Si lo entiendo, Ud. (usted) / ha dicho / (Ud.) dice / (tú) dices  ... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Si lo entiendo bien, Ud. (usted) quiere decir / tú, quieres decir que... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Si estoy en lo cierto... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Según he entendido... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Según Ud. (usted) / tú... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*)
- Repito lo que he entendido... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- A ver si lo he entendido... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Lo repito, (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Lo que Ud. (Usted) quiere decir con **esto** (se refiere al problema o tema planteado) es que... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).
- Le/Te digo lo dicho (se sobrentiende que vas a repetir o decir algo de lo ya dicho (participio de decir), con tus propias palabras y normalmente se utiliza si existe algo más de confianza o acercamiento con el profesor), ... (*y repites la idea con tus palabras*).

Comment: Great answer! I'm marking the other one just because it's older.

Comment: No te preocupes @capa, gracias a ti por el comentario. Solo espero que vayas mejorando tu español poco a poco.